# Is there a reference sheet I can print for the characters?

Tags: citadels, reference

I think Citadels is an *awesome* game, but playing our first game last night, I found many of us frequently wanted to refer to the character sheet in the rules to get an overview of all of the abilities.

I wish they'd included this information as a reference card.

Is there a PDF I can print with this info? Ideally it will be a nice small size.

Comment: When in a situation like this one thing that is having someone read the abilities out loud when someone has a question which should help people understand and remember them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good rule of thumb: when looking for a reference for a board or card game, always check BoardGameGeek. Here's the most popular Citadels reference available there:

https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/18772/universal-head-citadels-reference

And you can find a ton more in the Files section of the [Citadels detail page](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/478/citadels).

(I believe you have to sign up for an account to download files off BGG, but if you're into board games it's totally worth it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a reference sheet from an online copy of the rules or print off the pages of rules that you need to reference to for you games. Here is an online source for the [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f2/e7/f2e74a36-bed7-4a38-aff4-c2e968a1c369/citadels-rules-english.pdf) that can help you with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is one! It actually comes with the version of Citadels that I own.
The example pictures I found are in French and Italian though:

https://boardgamegeek.com/image/279467/citadels?size=original
https://boardgamegeek.com/image/51653/citadels?size=original